# Add values to an existing list inside a dictionary based on matching items from another dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I am struggling to merge values from a second dictionary to the initial one.

The initial dictionary is:

```
dictionary1 = {u'user1': [[u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A']],
                     u'user2': [[504, u'user2 Windows', u'date', u'date', u'20', u'', u'1']],
                     u'user3': [[511, u'user3 phone', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'1', u'E'],
                                   [125, u'user3 phone',u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'8'],
                                   [854, u'user3 phone', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'1', u'3'],
                                   [890, u'user3 Windows', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'4'],
                                   [506, u'user3 Windows', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'7'],
                                   [454, u'user3 Windows', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'E']]}


dictionary2 = {u'user1': [[u'N/A', u'N/A']],
                      u'user2': [[504, u'to_add']],
                      u'user3': [[890, u'to_add'],
                                    [506, u'to_add'],
                                    [454, u'to_add']]}
```

Matching values: 504 for user2, and 890, 506 and 454 for user 3. I would need the output to be:

```
dictionary1 = {u'user1': [[u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A']],
                     u'user2': [[504, u'user2 Windows', u'date', u'date', u'20', u'', u'1', u'to_add']],
                     u'user3': [[511, u'user3 phone', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'1', u'E'],
                                   [125, u'user3 phone',u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'8'],
                                   [854, u'user3 phone', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'1', u'3'],
                                   [890, u'user3 Windows', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'4', u'to_add'],
                                   [506, u'user3 Windows', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'7', u'to_add'],
                                   [454, u'user3 Windows', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'E', u'to_add']]}
```

I have tried multiple ways to check and match, but I am at a lost. Here is where I am stuck:

```
inter1 = []
for user1 in dictionary2:
    for details1 in dictionary2[user1]:
        inter1.append(details1[0])
        inter1.append(details1[1])
print inter1

a = [[details1[1] for details1 in dictionary2[user1]] for user1 in dictionary2]

inter2 = {}
for user2 in dictionary1:
    for details2 in dictionary1[user2]:
        if details2[0] in inter1:
            print user2, details2[2], details2[3], details2[4], details2[5], details2[6]
            inter2[user2] = [details2[2], details2[3], details2[4], details2[5], details2[6], inter1]
```

but this way just adds the entire list to the end of each list...:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate over a dictionary by using the `items()` method:

```
for k, v in dictionary2.items():
    print(k, v)
>>>user1 [['N/A', 'N/A']]
>>>user2 [[504, 'to_add']]
>>>user3 [[890, 'to_add'], [506, 'to_add'], [454, 'to_add']]
```

this should help you a lot

and second: you're overcomplicating things. why create intermediary dictionaries when you just want to modify dictionary1?

```
for k,v in dictionary2.items():
    for lst in v:
        for lst2 in dictionary1[k]:
            if lst[0] == lst2[0]:
                lst2 += lst[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it - posting here for whom else needs some ideas. It's not the most prettiest, but it works:

```
interm = {}
for user in dictionary1:
    if dictionary2[user]:
        interm[user] = []
        for element in dictionary1[user]:
            for element2 in dictionary2[user]:
                if str(element[0]) == str(element2[0]):
                    l = []
                    l.append(element[0])
                    l.append(element2[1])
                    interm[user].append(l)

for user in dictionary1:
    if interm[user]:
        for element3 in dictionary1[user]:
            for element4 in interm[user]:
                if str(element3[0]) == str(element4[0]):
                    element3.append(element4[1])
```

and the output becomes:

```
dictionary1 = {u'user3': [
    [511, u'user3 phone', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'1', u'E'],
    [125, u'user3 phone',u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'8'],
    [854, u'user3 phone', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'1', u'3'],
    [890, u'user3 Windows', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'4', u'to_add'],
    [506, u'user3 Windows', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'7', u'to_add'],
    [454, u'user3 Windows', u'date1', u'date2', u'name', u'', u'E', u'to_add']],
    u'user2': [
        [504, u'user2 Windows', u'date', u'date', u'20', u'', u'1', u'to_add']],
    u'user1': [[u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A', u'N/A']]}
```